# Barchart recognize time series data?

Tags: graphics, time-series, charts

I can't seem to get Barchart to recognize TimeSeries data. For example, my data is:

> {{1891, 1}, {1892, 1}, {1897, 1}, {1898, 1}, {1903, 1}, {1904,    1},
>   {1905, 1}, {1908, 4}, {1909, 6}, {1910, 6}, {1911, 16}, {1912,    33},
>   {1913, 35}, {1914, 43}, {1915, 39}, {1916, 31}, {1917,    42}, {1918,
>   52}, {1919, 44}, {1920, 53}, {1921, 33}, {1922,    18}, {1923, 8}}

But when I plot it using

```
BarChart[TimeSeries[data]]
```

I get this:

[image: barchart]

The problems are that it does not put the years values on the x-axis, and even worse it does treat the x-values as a linear time series. There should be gaps between 1892 and 1897, because there is no data for 1893, 1894, 1895 and 1896.

Comment: This is [documented](http://wolfram.com/xid/0cq0nbvj-c1j6si) behavior for `TimeSeries`, `EventSeries`, and `TemporalData`. Also, `BarChart` is a categorical plot, so it doesn't understand about gaps. You'd have to insert them, yourself. I'd suggest using `ListPlot[TimeSeries[data], Filling -> Axis]`, instead.

Comment: @rcollyer Hmm, that does create a stem plot which is of the right form, but if I want to make a BarChart there is no way except to create fake data with 0 values for the gaps and then add in the x-labels manually too? Seems kind of onerous.

Comment: Apparently, `TimeSeries` can be resampled without much drama, see Kirma's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Module[{data, range},
 data = TimeSeries[#, ResamplingMethod -> {"Constant", 0}] &@{{1891, 
     1}, {1892, 1}, {1897, 1}, {1898, 1}, {1903, 1}, {1904, 1}, {1905,
      1}, {1908, 4}, {1909, 6}, {1910, 6}, {1911, 16}, {1912, 
     33}, {1913, 35}, {1914, 43}, {1915, 39}, {1916, 31}, {1917, 
     42}, {1918, 52}, {1919, 44}, {1920, 53}, {1921, 33}, {1922, 
     18}, {1923, 8}};
 range = Range[data["FirstTime"], data["LastTime"]];
 BarChart[data /@ range, 
  ChartLabels -> Placed[range, Below, Rotate[#, Pi/2.4] &], 
  ImageSize -> Large]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! That's cheating. :) (+1)

Comment: @rcollyer I'd like to have some other constant than 0 for missing data, but in that case chart labels for missing data seem to be also omitted.

Comment: I don't know, I don't mind the gaps when using `Missing["NotAvailable"]` as the constant. But, it works just fine as is.

Comment: Great answer !!!